# Sending persian string with socket from python to python

Tags: python, sockets, encoding, raspberry-pi3, persian

I want to send an Persian(farsi) string with socket from python to another python in raspberry. I see some question mark in terminal and when write that in a txt file i see ÇÝÔÇÑ characters(for a word).
server code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1256 -*-
import sys
import time
import os
import SocketServer
import thread
import os.path
import webbrowser
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO



    class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
        """
            The reques

t handler class for our server.

        It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
        override the handle() method to implement communication to the
        client.
        """

    def handle(self):
        try:
            # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])


            text2=self.data

            print type(text2)

            text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
            text_file.write(text2)
            text_file.close()
            completeURL="http://10.7.6.172/GanjSearch.aspx?q=/%s/" %text2
            print completeURL
            webbrowser.open(completeURL) 

        except Exception, e:
            print type(e)
            print e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "192.168.1.55", 9998
    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    try:
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
        # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
        # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
        server.serve_forever()
    except Exception, e:
            print type(e)
            print e
```

client code:

```
a="persian-word"
socket.sendall(a)
```

what must i do?

Comment: You should post your code, so that we see what you do.

Comment: You encode your Farsi-sign in its UTF16 representation, then send over socket and decode it again to farsi sign. For example if you want the UTF16 decimal of the sign you decode it with **int(repr(data.decode('utf-16'))[4:8], 16)** when your "data" is the farsi sign

Comment: @Dr.JohnJamesCobra, if i want string not int, i must write string(repr(data.decode('utf-16'))[4:8], 16) ???    and how i must code encode?

Comment: not string but "str"; you can work with utf table at http://www.fileformat.info/ and find encoding example at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` instead of `# -*- coding: cp1256 -*-` in top of both code(client and server). so without used of decode and encode functions, it work correctly.